# Automatically play a UDP video stream using KODI

Tags: kodi

There is a streamer which streams video using UDP.I want to input that UDP stream address in KODI.Once KODI starts its starts playing the video from that address.Prsently I am using a .strm file containing the UDP address stored on a pendrive.I select the path and make it play.I don't want to use a pendrive.
Where can I save the .strm file for KODI to automatically play it other than the storage?
Is there any add-on in KODI where I can input the UDP stream address and port and save it to automatically play it always when it starts.